# PFFile security

Tags: security, parse-platform, pffile

Does anyone know if it is possible to set security to a PFFile?
The URL to a PFFile is public and can be access by anyone who knows the URL.
I need my URLs to have access control, not public access.
Can that be done in Parse?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wrap access to your file in a proxy with your own security checks.

Look into Parse hosting, you basically create a web end-point that takes the file ID and User Token as input then you check security and return the file data in your response stream.

If you need help implementing it after reading the docs please post another question with what you've tried so far.